# Easiest way to switch between /etc/hosts mappings in a browser

Tags: google-chrome, dns, browser, hosts-file

I have a web application that connects with various services and the only way to develop it is to use exactly the same domain for development as for production. I do it by overriding the domain in /etc/hosts to point to localhost when I need to develop it. That however is a painful development workflow, I have to edit /etc/hosts everytime I need to switch and clear Chromium cache. Is there any method that would make it easier? Is it possible to override DNS directly in Chromium so for example I could set up a separate browser profile for development?

Comment: "Is it possible to override DNS directly in Chromium so for example I could set up a separate browser profile for development?" - Modifying the hosts file actually already does this.  Your current method of modifying the hosts file is the approach you should be using.  I assume you don't have a configuration that allows you to update your DNS in any other fashion (i.e. a Window Server which is the DNS provider to the machine attached to it)

Comment: Do you literally mean `/etc/hosts` on Linux/BSD, or are you talking about a Windows system here?

Comment: Literally, I'm on Linux

Comment: @Ramhound yes but I'm wondering if there's something more flexible available, other than changing hosts file.

Comment: @MaciejKrawczyk - Yes, use a DNS server you have full control over, which you can update instantly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the hostname, use DNAT to change where the IP address goes:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d $prod_ip -j DNAT --to-destination $test_ip
[…]
iptables -t nat -F OUTPUT
```

```
nft add chain ip nat input '{ type nat hook input priority -150; policy accept; }'
nft add chain ip nat output '{ type nat hook output priority -150; policy accept; }'
nft add rule ip nat output ip daddr $prod_ip dnat to $test_ip
[…]
nft flush chain ip nat output
```